# Check if Elasticsearch has run in the last X hours though no document is indexed

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, document, scheduling

I want to check if elastic search has run in the last X hours even when it has no document to index. In the sense, I want to know if there is no indexing because there is no document to index or because elastic search stopped running, basically data freshness.

Comment: You would need to add a new field `timestamp` with every document you index and perform sort on it. ES Index has lot of operations apart from ingestion for e.g. it performs other internal operations for e.g. `merge` in cleaning up deleting docs, or when a user performs index settings update etc. To have an inbuilt field to keep time track would be expensive. https://discuss.elastic.co/t/get-last-update-time-for-an-index/77365/4

Comment: I want that field to be updated whenever elasticsearch runs, not just when the document is alone updated. Only then I come to know if the problem is with database being empty or elastic search has not run